# What form param values can be used for TRUE in a ruby on rails app with mysql db for a BOOLEAN field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, boolean

when contructing a http form parameter for a Boolean, what value ca be used to represent true?

That is, ruby on rails database field set to BOOLEAN for a mysql database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A value of `1` will evaluate to `true` and `0` will evaluate to `false`.

A good little reference/example is [available here.](http://www.softiesonrails.com/2008/4/6/absolute-moron-s-guide-to-forms-in-rails-part-3)